# Adding custom id attribute for img and input elements

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to add a custom id attribute for each img & input elements in ckeditor 3.6.4.
So far I have added dataProcessor.htmlFilter to handle the id attribute like this

```
        CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function(event) {     
            var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor;

            editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules(
            {
                elements: {
                    $: function (element) {
                        if ( (element.name == 'img' || element.name == 'input') && CKEDITOR.instances.editor.mode == 'wysiwyg' ) {
                            if (!element.attributes.id){
                                var g = createID();
                                alert('new id: ' + g);
                                element.attributes.id = g;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

and when I add a new textfield in visual editor I do get a new id. But if I set to the source mode the mode is still 'wysiwyg' and not 'source' and it gives a new Id.

How can I prevent the double action?

---

Did some testing. Added this

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor.on('mode', function() {
            // Code to execute when the user switches editing modes
                alert('Changed to: ' + CKEDITOR.instances.editor.mode);
            });
```

Somehow that fires after the htmlFilter rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went with plan B

Customized the widgets needed and added the id attribute in plugin. Was easy and fast.

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding a check for the editor mode to your rule.

```
if ( (element.name == 'img' || element.name == 'input') && editor.mode == "wysiwyg" ) {
    if (!element.attributes.id){
        var g = createID();
        alert('new id: ' + g);
        element.attributes.id = g;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure whether "editor" would be the correct object name to use, you may want to use  `CKEDITOR.currentInstance.mode`
There is also a `getMode()` method.

---

Here are some api references for the items mentioned:
[`mode` property](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#mode)
[`currentInstance` property](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html#.currentInstance)
[`getMode()` method](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#getMode)

Comment: Tried that, but something strange is going on. I keep getting 'wysiwyg' to the editor mode. I will add some more data to my question